# What ODBC Driver is compatible with SQL SERVER 2017 to configure system DSN?

Tags: sql-server-2017

Currently, we are using ODBC Driver 13 to configure system DSN for SQL Server 2016 database. We are going to upgrade system from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2017. We are not able to upgrade system using ODBC Driver 13 with SQL Server 2017. It seems ODBC driver 13 is having support upto SQL Server 2016.
So we are looking for higher version of ODBC driver.

Thanks,
Santosh.